# How to access files of GitHub Action repo when using that action in another repo?

Tags: javascript, github, github-actions

I have created a JavaScript automation and in that script I have created couple of YML files and I'm importing them using fs and js-yaml libraries. I have hosted this code in repo A.

I want to convert my repo A into a GitHub action. I have followed the [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/creating-a-javascript-action) from GitHub to create JavaScript action. I have used the [verbal/ncc](https://github.com/vercel/ncc) to create one file with all my libraries as suggested by GitHub.

But when I use this action in repo B, I get an error saying the yml files are not available at the mentioned path.

Does GitHub workflow download the action's repo during execution? if yes, how can I pass these yml files into the script?

If not, what are the options to pass these files into script?

Comment: Please show how you're using the action. Also, what is the visibility of the repository containing the action? Private? Internal? Public?

Comment: Both the repositories are Internal and in same organization. I'm using the action with 1. uses (org_name/repo_name@main) and 2. with - inputs, that I defined in action.yml.

Comment: Please update your question to contain a [minimal reproducer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 7):

You can access an action repository files in a **composite action** from the `action.yml` file by using the `${{ github.action_path }}` context variable.

> The path where an action is located. This property is only supported in composite actions. You can use this path to access files located in the same repository as the action.
> Blockquote

*Source: [Github Documentation about Context](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts)*

For example, if you need to execute a python script `script.py` located in the action repository from a **`run` step in a composite action**, you would have to use something like this:

```yaml
run: python "${{ github.action_path }}/script.py"
shell: bash
```

*Note: I suggest to inform the **shell** to avoid problem as composite actions can be used on any OS runner.*

I've created a [small action](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/convert-json-to-env/blob/main/action.yml) as reference which uses this concept if you want to have a look.